# Снятие баланса и проверка баланса PHP

Tags: php

Нужно чтобы когда юзер кликает на кнопку, то с его баланса списывалось 1 тысяча.
Но если его баланс меньше чем тысяча хотя бы на 1, то выдавало ошибку `$paymenttext_error`.

```
if($_POST['payments']) 
{
  $rp = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `Name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")->num_rows;
  if($rp >= 1) 
  {
    if($_POST['payments']) 
    {
      $mysql->query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `pLevel` = `pLevel`-1000 WHERE `Name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
      $paymenttext_success = "Баланс был успешно снят! [Код: 1]";
    } 
    else
    {
      $paymenttext_error = "Ошибка при выполнении. >> отрицательный баланс [Код: 2]";
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    $paymenttext_login = "Войдите в личный кабинет!!! [Код: 3]";
  }
}
```

Кнопка вызывающая этот скрипт:

```
<input type="submit" name="payments" value="Сменить пароль>
```

Answer (score 1):

начнем с того что вы скорее всего вообще не понимаете что вы делаете:

```
  $rp = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `Name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")->num_rows;
```

этот запрос получает цифру, т.е. количество строк которые вернула mysql.
1. Допустим в сесси null есть вариант, что и в базе данных буде строка с именем null и у кого снимет баланс непонятно!
2. Все же нас интересует не количество строк, а именно pLevel потому стоит строку немного переписать.

```
    if(is_string($_SESSION['username'])){
       $rp = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `Name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
       if($rp->num_rows >= 1) {
          $row = $rp->fetch_assoc();
          if($row['pLevel']>999){
             // Здесь снимаем баланс
          }else{
            // Здесь ошибка, что у вас нет на балансе
          }
       }else{
         // Здесь ошибка что такого юзера нет
       }
   }else{
    // Здесь ошибка, что не авторизован
  }
```

В итоге получается всего-то надо, читать документацию, не пользоваться старыми функциями, проверять, что прислал юзер (обязательно), и делать выводы в сторону изучения работы с БД

Comment: Можно пояснить за что отвечает if($rp->num_rows >= 1) ?

Comment: >Можно пояснить за что отвечает if($rp->num_rows >= 1)  
количество строк которые вернула mysql

Comment: вы думаете там может быть больше одной строки, да? :)

Comment: и замените `*` на какой нибудь `id`, а то если там бинарное поле с картинкой будет, то это снизит производительность.

Comment: @teran *... и замените `*` на какой нибудь `id` ...* - лучше на искомый `pLevel`